# UIView position relative to photo taken

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, image, image-processing

I have a `UIViewController` which consists of several `UIView` elements. From this view controller a photo is taken using `AVCapturePhotoOutput`.
Then, from the output, `UIImage` is built.

Is it possible to know the position of a specific UIView seen on a preview layer (lets say `SpecificView`) in the result image? For example, I'd like to draw a horizontal line on the image at the position where `SpecificView` was when taking a photo.

I can get `SpecificView.y` relative to `UIWindow`, then multiply it by `UIScreen.main.scale` to get pixels but it doesn't seem to be solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to set image inside specific UIview? like click on UIview to select image and set on that view UIimage right?

Comment: Not really. Imagine that there is a camera preview and on this preview there are some views. I would like to know the position of these views on resulting UIImage. The problem is image can have some high resolution, for example 2000x4000. So question is how to map my view position (which frame is e.g. [0, 500, 100, 100]) into the image coordinate system

Comment: You're mixing two different things `UIView` and `UIImage`. That's why your question is a bit confusing. I assume your gonna show the image in UIImageView, in that case use one of the `convert` methods of `UIView` to get coordinates in relation to each other.

Comment: Are you wanting to draw them to the image or are you just wanting to add them back over an imageview in the relative position?

Comment: Well I'm not going to show this image in `UIImageView`. Just want to do some operations on `UIImage` and, for example, save to a file or upload somewhere.